# Swift 4: Passing Data from Tableview to ViewController

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

So I have been spending the last two days on this and I can positively say that I am stuck.

so, I created a tableview linked to a custom cell, I have an array of items already set and in the right order within each section when I build it, all that is fine and dandy BUT I CANNOT SEEM TO PASS INFORMATION! haha. I keep getting errors! I am gonna try to be as detailed as possible as i am new here (and a 3 week old coder #beginner) and not sure how much info I can attach but here goes nothing:

these are my arrays and table functions:

```
var foodKind = [["Whole eggs", "Bacon", "16oz water"],["80% Ground beef", "Avacado", "16oz water"],["Lettuce burger", "Avacado Salad", "16oz water"],["Tri-pep"],["MTS Machine Whey", "Tri-Pep"]]
var itemCount =  [["4 boiled", "3 Slice", "1 bottle"],["6oz", "1 whole", "1 bottle"],["1 burger", "2 cups", "1 bottle"], ["1 serving"], ["1 scoop", "1 serving"]]

var count = [3, 3, 3, 1, 2]

var foodImage = [[#imageLiteral(resourceName: "hard boiled eggs"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bacon"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "water")], [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "ground beef"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avacdo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "water")],[ #imageLiteral(resourceName: "lettuce wrap burger"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "avacado salad 1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "water")], [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "tri-pep aminos")], [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "mtswhey-2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "tri-pep aminos")]]

var sections = ["Breakfast: 450 calories", "Lunch: 650 calories", "Dinner: 543 calories","Pre-Workout calories: 0", "PostWorkout: 153 calories"]
var selectedIndex = Int()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dietTableView.delegate = self
   //dietTableView.dataSource = self

        self.dietTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "custom")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count[section]


}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 5
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : CustomTableViewCell = self.dietTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "custom") as! CustomTableViewCell


    cell.itemName.text = foodKind[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.itemCount.text = itemCount[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.itemPicture.image = foodImage[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
return cell
```

Heres is my "didselectrow", and "preparesegue" functions:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Item", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Item" {
        let vc : ItemViewController = segue.destination as! ItemViewController



        vc.count = itemCount[selectedIndex]
        vc.image = foodImage[selectedIndex]
        vc.name = foodKind[selectedIndex]
```

This is the ItemViewController variables:

```
var name : [String] = [""]   //this is the only way I can code it without getting an error.

var image = [UIImage]()   // lost here

var count : [String] = [""]   //this is the only way I can code it without getting an error.


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.itemName.text = String(describing: name)

    self.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: image) //not working!!! Cant seem to find the right code for this from converting UIIMAGE to String. I am just lost!

    self.itemCount.text = String(describing: count)
```

Here's a screenshot of the error code I get for the "Image" variable:

[image]

When I leave out the Image (since I can't figure the code for) I build the app and I get this:

[image]

[This will give you a visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0F9M.jpg)

Comment: Valerino error is very common , you can not pass array of UIImage in image init, the expected argument is string value.So pass image name as string (ex-: "MyImage.png").Do something like -:  self.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: image[0]) and get string value from particular index, and instead of array of UIImage make array of string holding your image names or url.

Comment: ex-: var image = [String]() . Now in this array save image name that you have in assets, or if you are getting data from server parse JSON and fetch string URL, and append in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem seems simple:

```
var image = [UIImage]()   // lost here
```

That's an ARRAY of images.

Suggest for a single item, you want a single image?

```
var image:UIImage!
```

Warning, will crash if image is nil when used. (alternate use UIImage? but must unwrap).

Therereby, in the table view controller..

```
vc.image = foodImage[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Will be behave as expected. No need to use:

```
self.itemImage.image = UIImage(named: image) //not working!!! Cant seem to find the right code for this from converting UIIMAGE to String. I am just lost!
```

(Which is incorrect because you're trying to use an array of images to pass to the STRING parameter of load image from file.)

Just use:

```
self.itemImage.image = self.image
```

As they are both image types.

You do the correct thing in the cell and index the array within the array to get the image, so do the same here and have a singe image type in your detail view controller. In that way if you click beef, the image for beef is sent.

As an aside, consider using a data model type for your recipe.

```
class Ingredient {
var name:String = ""
var image:UIImage! = nil
var count:Int = 0
var calories:Int = 0

public init(name: String, image: UIImage, count: Int, calories: Int) {
self.name = name
self.image = image
self.count = count
self.calories = calories
}
}
```

then you can do say:

```
let ingredients = [Ingredient("Beef", beefImage, 100, 350), Ingredient("Onion", onionImage, 1, 20)]
```

or etc,

Comment: Thanks for your time! I am trying to use an array of images and not just one image...

Comment: The item detail needs to display more than one image? or do you mean the tableview has an array of images, but the item view only shows one image?

Comment: if you look at the tableview picture I attached, I want it to show the picture of the table row I am tapping on in the itemviewcontroller.

Comment: Revised my answer, most important question: Does the detail page need to show just the beef if you click the beef?

Comment: Yes! I see what you're asking! If i click beef i want it to have the name "ground beef" above the picture and the serving below the picture. And that goes for every other item I pick. Does that make sense?

Comment: If I pick boiled eggs then i want it to show a picture of boiled eggs and etc.

Comment: Updated my answer, mainly just remove the array from your item view controller and make it a single UIImage! type, and make sure to assign the foodImage[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] when creating view controller.

Comment: The problem seems to be with my two dimensional array. I do as you say and it comes back as: "Cannot assign value of type '[UIImage]' to type 'UIImage!'" Its does the same for the other two!    var name = ""     sent to = vc.name = foodName[selectedIndex] and i get: "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String'" Same thing with vc.count. I can get it to work if i take off my two dimensional array but then the order in each section will be off!

Comment: Added a picture so you can visually see what I am seeing-with the description: "this will give you a visual"

Comment: I created a class for it and that did the trick. Thanks for your help!